# Netty: how to catch "java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: java, netty

I searched the web and the threads I foud are all about why it happens and how to avoid/resolve it from the client side. But at the server side, I cannot always fully control a client's behavor (e.g. power outrage). When this happen, I would like to catch it and release the session resources. This exception does not go through the pipeline and `pipeline.addLast(new ExceptionHandler())` does not help. How can I catch it? My Netty version: 4.1.58.Final.

Comment: `Channel` has `closeFuture()` that you can use to register listener which will be called when channel is closed. Or you can just implement `io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext, Throwable)` in your handler

Comment: @rkosegi - I implemented `io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext, Throwable)` and `addLast` to the pipeline, but it is not called, that's why I think the esception does not go through the pipeline.

Comment: In my handler, extending `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`, I override the `exceptionCaught` method and I get all kind of exceptions, from where I can decide if they are "normal" (as conncetion reset by peer) and silently ignored (except closing server side operations) or to act on.

Comment: @Frederic - confirm that the exception was caught, thank you.

Comment: @Frederic - confirm overriding the `exceptionCaught` in `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` cannot capture `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer`. As I said, it seems the exception did not go to the pipeline and a handler register to the pipeline cannot catch it.

Comment: Strange since I had this exception in my own code:
Here the TrappedFactory for exception, including IOException
https://github.com/fredericBregier/Waarp-All/blob/19361e9830bcd972f15fa564d581015b66603949/WaarpR66/src/main/java/org/waarp/openr66/protocol/exception/OpenR66ExceptionTrappedFactory.java#L59
Here when it is used from execptionCaught override:
https://github.com/fredericBregier/Waarp-All/blob/19361e9830bcd972f15fa564d581015b66603949/WaarpR66/src/main/java/org/waarp/openr66/protocol/networkhandler/NetworkServerHandler.java#L420